# Books for vector analysis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, book-recommendation

In the beginning of Griffiths electrodynamics there is a section for Vector analysis. All that was taught in very brief and I would like to read it in detail from a mathematical perspective rather than a Physics. I want a book on VECTOR ANALYSIS which has all topics such as Dirac delta function vector fields theory, Spherical coordinates, curl,divergence, gradient, potentials etc and basically has all topics. I have a good understanding on single variable calculus. Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to search for materials for vector analysis(not including Dirac delta function. This is a somewhat more complex concept), you can refer to Fleming's book Functions of Several Variables. And for references for Dirac delta function, I recommend Grubb's book Distributions and Operators(Graduate Texts in Mathematics, vol. 252). The third chapter will introduce the concept and the subsequent chapters are applying such kinds of functions to the study of partial differential equations(including the harmonic equation, which is used in electrodynamics).

Answer (score 0):

*Schaum's Vector Analysis(second edition)*. You can use this as a textbook or as a supplement. I have read this when I was taking a formal course on Fluid Dynamics and I used Schaum's book as a supplement to F. Chorlton's book.